# Unable to find svgs assets with Parcel in React and TS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, svg, parceljs

I've added parcel to a `create-react-app` project that uses the typescript template. I'm trying to add svgs to my outputted js file following the recommendations from [their docs](https://parceljs.org/languages/svg/#importing-as-a-react-component). I'm not sure if there's something that has to be done differently in TS, but I set up my project as they suggested as their JSX snippets and it didn't work:

.parcelrc

```json
{
  "extends": "@parcel/config-default",
  "transformers": {
    "jsx:*.svg": ["...", "@parcel/transformer-svg-react"]
  }
}
```

Note: I've added the transformer plugin to my dev deps.

Component.tsx

```js
import BriefcaseSvg from "jsx:../../assets/briefcase.svg";

// ...later in my return statement:
<img src={BriefcaseSvg} alt="work icon" />

// I've also tried
<BriefcaseSvg/>
```

Every time I get the following error:

`Cannot resolve dependency 'jsx:../../assets/briefcase.svg'`

I've also tried converting both `jsx` declarations to `tsx`.

I've added parcel on top of the standard webpack build tool you get with CRA. Wepback has no problem and displays the icon just find. Parcel also was able to run a build when I didn't include this svg plugin but outputted the svg separately in its own file.

I'd like everything to end up in one js file. How can I achieve this with parcel, react, and TS?

Answer (score 1):

The default parcel config defines an svg transformer and optimizer, which are not properly resolving imports. You can follow the issue on GitHub at https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/7587.

As a workaround (for any type of import), you do not need to import a transformer.

Replace "jsx:" with "url:" in your import like this:

```
import BriefcaseSvg from "url:../../assets/briefcase.svg";
```

And use the src attribute, not a component.

```
<img src={BriefcaseSvg} alt="work icon" />
```

You can read more about the syntax at https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/pull/4055. It only works in JS and was meant to support importing files that are not explicitly supported.